# Strange version increment with Hibernate and @LastModifiedDate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I created a small test case using Spring Boot 1.5.3, Spring JPA and Hibernate 5.2.10. I created this test case when I noticed strange things in my application using Hibernate envers: I had several rows in audit table with same data. So, also if the entity was unchanged I had a new row in audit table.

I created then this test case focusing on Hibernate. I created a simple entity:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners({ AuditingEntityListener.class})
public class TestEntity extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7939807161238741482L;

    private String name;

    // Trick to start version counting from 1 instead of 0
    @Version
    private int version = 1;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedDate(LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }
}
```

Nothing special here; just the AuditingEntityListener that permit to set the latModifiedDate automatically.
This is the test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
public class HibernateTests {
    private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityRepository testEntityRepository;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        testEntityRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void checkVersionAfterUpdateWithoutChanges() {
        TestEntity testEntity = new TestEntity();
        testEntity.setName("Name");
        testEntity = testEntityRepository.save(testEntity);

        assertEquals(1, testEntity.getVersion());

        // saving again the user without changes
        testEntity = testEntityRepository.save(testEntity);

        assertEquals(1, testEntity.getVersion());

    }

}
```

Note I'm not using @Transactional because I want simulate that different transactions make a save of the object.
What am I doing? I create a TestEntity object, I saved that and I checked the version is 1. This assertion succedeed. Then I resaved the same object without any changes and I expected Hibernate didn't make any update on the database, instead the assertion fails because it returns 2 as version.

Removing the AuditingEntityListener from my entity instead the test passes!
Is this a desired behaviour? How can I avoid Hibernate make an update when the object is NOT changed at all?

=============================================

Small update: I debugged Hibernate code until arrive to the point where there is the problem: TypeHelper.findDirty(). As expected the method find the lastModifiedDate is changed (it return an array with the index of the field changed).
Should't lastModifiedDate be updated after the dirty check control? The object should be updated only if some property is changed, but change the modification date will make the object always elegible to be updated in the databse. I don't see the point of this...